# Extracting text between quotation marks in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

My file contains above 2000 abstracts containing above 18000 sentences, starting with tag  and ending in tag . I want to find the information by use of notepad++,
A view of my file is as below:

```
<abstract>
<sentence>Activationofthe<conslex="CD28_surface_receptor"sem="G#protein_family_or_group"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>surfacereceptor</cons>providesamajorcostimulatorysignalfor<conslex="T_cell_activation"sem="G#other_name">Tcellactivation</cons>resultinginenhancedproductionof<conslex="interleukin-2"sem="G#protein_molecule">interleukin-2</cons>(<conslex="IL-2"sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons>)and<conslex="cell_proliferation"sem="G#other_name">cellproliferation</cons>.</sentence>  
<sentence>In<conslex="primary_T_lymphocyte"sem="G#cell_type">primaryTlymphocytes</cons>weshowthat<conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>ligationleadstotherapidintracellularformationof<conslex="reactive_oxygen_intermediate"sem="G#inorganic">reactiveoxygenintermediates</cons>(<conslex="ROI"sem="G#inorganic">ROIs</cons>)whicharerequiredfor<conslex="CD28-mediated_activation"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>-mediatedactivation</cons>ofthe<conslex="NF-kappa_B"sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-kappaB</cons>/<conslex="CD28-responsive_complex"sem="G#protein_complex"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>-responsivecomplex</cons>and<conslex="IL-2_expression"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="IL-2"sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons>expression</cons>.</sentence>  
<sentence>Delineationofthe<conslex="CD28_signaling_cascade"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>signalingcascade</cons>wasfoundtoinvolve<conslex="protein_tyrosine_kinase_activity"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="protein_tyrosine_kinase"sem="G#protein_family_or_group">proteintyrosinekinase</cons>activity</cons>,followedbytheactivationof<conslex="phospholipase_A2"sem="G#protein_molecule">phospholipaseA2</cons>and<conslex="5-lipoxygenase"sem="G#protein_molecule">5-lipoxygenase</cons>.</sentence>  
<sentence>Ourdatasuggestthat<conslex="lipoxygenase_metabolite"sem="G#protein_family_or_group"><conslex="lipoxygenase"sem="G#protein_molecule">lipoxygenase</cons>metabolites</cons>activate<conslex="ROI_formation"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="ROI"sem="G#inorganic">ROI</cons>formation</cons>whichtheninduce<conslex="IL-2"sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons>expressionvia<conslex="NF-kappa_B_activation"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="NF-kappa_B"sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-kappaB</cons>activation</cons>.</sentence>  
<sentence>Thesefindingsshouldbeusefulfor<conslex="therapeutic_strategies"sem="G#other_name">therapeuticstrategies</cons>andthedevelopmentof<conslex="immunosuppressants"sem="G#other_name">immunosuppressants</cons>targetingthe<conslex="CD28_costimulatory_pathway"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>costimulatorypathway</cons>.</sentence>
</abstract>
```

I want to extract the text between quotation marks e.g. my desired output is like this

```
"CD28_surface_receptor"   "G#protein_family_or_group"    "CD28" "G#protein_molecule"  
"primary_T_lymphocyte"    "G#cell_type"
```

i hope there will be a simpler way of doing so with notepad++ through use of regx. task may become easy if there is a way to extract the text on the basis of color in notepad++

Comment: The first line of your desired output contains only 4 texts between quotes, while the first line containing them has more than 4 (I count 12). Do you need only these 4 or all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Check the below

```
"\w+"|"G#\w+"
```

or operator | works in lateste notepad ++ only

Comment: "or operator | works in lateste notepad ++ only" This is totally untrue.