# Extracting text between each quotation marks from file in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

My file contains above 2000 abstracts containing above 18000 sentences, starting with tag and ending in tag . I want to find the information by use of notepad++, A view of my file is as below:

```
<abstract>
<sentence>Activationofthe<conslex="CD28_surface_receptor"sem="G#protein_family_or_group"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>surfacereceptor</cons>providesamajorcostimulatorysignalfor<conslex="T_cell_activation"sem="G#other_name">Tcellactivation</cons>resultinginenhancedproductionof<conslex="interleukin-2"sem="G#protein_molecule">interleukin-2</cons>(<conslex="IL-2"sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons>)and<conslex="cell_proliferation"sem="G#other_name">cellproliferation</cons>.</sentence> 
<sentence>In<conslex="primary_T_lymphocyte"sem="G#cell_type">primaryTlymphocytes</cons>weshowthat<conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>ligationleadstotherapidintracellularformationof<conslex="reactive_oxygen_intermediate"sem="G#inorganic">reactiveoxygenintermediates</cons>(<conslex="ROI"sem="G#inorganic">ROIs</cons>)whicharerequiredfor<conslex="CD28-mediated_activation"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>-mediatedactivation</cons>ofthe<conslex="NF-kappa_B"sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-kappaB</cons>/<conslex="CD28-responsive_complex"sem="G#protein_complex"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>-responsivecomplex</cons>and<conslex="IL-2_expression"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="IL-2"sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons>expression</cons>.</sentence>  
<sentence>Delineationofthe<conslex="CD28_signaling_cascade"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>signalingcascade</cons>wasfoundtoinvolve<conslex="protein_tyrosine_kinase_activity"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="protein_tyrosine_kinase"sem="G#protein_family_or_group">proteintyrosinekinase</cons>activity</cons>,followedbytheactivationof<conslex="phospholipase_A2"sem="G#protein_molecule">phospholipaseA2</cons>and<conslex="5-lipoxygenase"sem="G#protein_molecule">5-lipoxygenase</cons>.</sentence>  
<sentence>Ourdatasuggestthat<conslex="lipoxygenase_metabolite"sem="G#protein_family_or_group"><conslex="lipoxygenase"sem="G#protein_molecule">lipoxygenase</cons>metabolites</cons>activate<conslex="ROI_formation"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="ROI"sem="G#inorganic">ROI</cons>formation</cons>whichtheninduce<conslex="IL-2"sem="G#protein_molecule">IL-2</cons>expressionvia<conslex="NF-kappa_B_activation"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="NF-kappa_B"sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-kappaB</cons>activation</cons>.</sentence>  
<sentence>Thesefindingsshouldbeusefulfor<conslex="therapeutic_strategies"sem="G#other_name">therapeuticstrategies</cons>andthedevelopmentof<conslex="immunosuppressants"sem="G#other_name">immunosuppressants</cons>targetingthe<conslex="CD28_costimulatory_pathway"sem="G#other_name"><conslex="CD28"sem="G#protein_molecule">CD28</cons>costimulatorypathway</cons>.</sentence>
</abstract>
```

I want to extract the text between quotation marks or in other words want to remove all data except that is in double quotes throughout the text e.g. my desired output is like this

```
CD28_surface_receptor  G#protein_family_or_group   CD28   G#protein_molecule  
primary_T_lymphocyte   G#cell_type
```

I used `.*"(.*)".*` in *Find What* and then replace with `\1` by replacing all. It only extracted the text having quotations, from the last of each line but I want to extract from all doc and from each line as there are more string having double quotes in my file.

Comment: Why are you posting duplicates? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409502/extracting-text-between-quotation-marks-in-notepad

Comment: I was got logout and don't remember my that password

Comment: My this problem have not solved yet

Comment: Why specificaly with notepad++ ? Can't you use another tool (grep/awk) ?

Comment: I did not used these tool yet

Comment: i used .*"(.*)".* in find what and then replace  with \1 by replacing all. It only extracted the text having quotations, from the last of each line but i want to extract from all doc and from each line as there are more string having double quotes in my file

Comment: Did the answer below help or do you need more assistance?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `[^"]*"([^"]+)"[^"]*` in *Find What*, and replace with `\1\r\n`:

[image]

Or, to have them tab-separated, replace with `\1\t`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works great for me, I have a similar problem. One question, if I want the output to include the "quotation" marks, how would I change the regexp? Edit: Using "\1"\r\n works, wow Regexp is so simple! ...

Comment: Either add them to the replacement string where they should be or move them inside the `(...)` capturing group: `[^"]*("[^"]+")[^"]*`

Comment: Thanks :D I upvoted the question, even tho it's a bit Engrishian (Engrish Indian) I wanted to ask a similar question but the poor guy already got hammered for asking a duplicate :P

Comment: Thnaks @WiktorStribiżew.. Its working in second Case